# FlowDocument Force a PageBreak (BreakPageBefore)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using C# to create a FlowDocument and fill it with data within a table.

**Example:**

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
Table table1 = new Table();
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table1); 

table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];
table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];
currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Report"))));
```

I want to be able to force a page break after every 'section' of data.
I have found the *BreakPageBefore* but cant figure out how to force a Page Break.

Any examples would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand right you want to do this:

```
Section section = new Section();
section.BreakPageBefore = true;
section.Blocks.Add(table1);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(section);
```

If you want to break within a table i suggest it would be better to make a new table.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I was after. I wanted a simple PageBreak kind of thing.

TableData..
TableData..
<PageBreak>
TableData...

ETC...

If this is what I'm after, I've missed it and could you explain please?

Many Thank.

Comment: Sounds like you want to start a new table for each section as martin suggests, eg <FlowDocument><Table PageBreakBefore="true"><TableData><TableData>...</Table><Table PageBreakBefore="true"><TableData><TableData>....

Comment: I think like Ray it described in XAML it's the best way. Every Block-type has the PageBreakBefore-property you could use to say to the FlowDocument that it should break. I think there is no other way. So far i haven't found something like a PageBreak-type the explictly could make a page break.

Comment: @Ray Burns It is worth noting that even though `Table`  has the `PageBreakBefore` property it doesn't seem to get honored by the flow document. You really have to place the table in a section. Maybe adding a table to a flow doc automatically wraps it in a section behind the scenes.